# Cannot create object from another file

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have this class in **TestInput.cs** file,

```
 public class HDate
 {
        private string StartYear;

        public string StartYear1
        {
            get { return StartYear; }
            set { StartYear = value; }
        }

        public HDate() { }

        public HDate(){
           DateTime today = DateTime.Now;
           //Some Code here
        }

     return StartDate+';'+EndDate; // ???
 }
```

Then i'm going to create an object from that class.This file is **Inputsubmit.cs** file

```
 if(ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count < 0)
         {
          HDate hd = new HDate()
          hd.

         }
```

What i'm getting then automatically create new class for HDate.. but already i have a class on another file know ?

Comment: Are you having them on different namespaces

Comment: Seems like a namespace trouble. Which namespace contains HDate, and which contains the class you're trying to use HDate from?

Comment: Could it be that HDate doesn't compile? - e.g. There is no definition give for `EndDate`. Also, what is that return statement doing there?

Comment: Same Namespace.in inputsubmit.cs files class is  public class InputSubmit
    {

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you could clarify what actually happens when you try to construct a `HDate`. However, your `HDate` class has two constructors with the same signature. The compiler won't be able to determine which one to call, so you need to remove one of them before you can make `HDate` objects.

Answer (score 0):

Unless what you've shown is a much cut-down sample of the declaration for `HDate`, it could be that the `HDate` class doesn't compile, so intellisense won't pick it up.

In particular you've got the line:  `return StartDate+';'+EndDate; // ???`

That is just in the class declaration, not in a method, and refers to `StartDate` and `EndDate` which I can't see declarations for.

Comment: i just paste the part of the code.I just wanted to know how can i access datamambers from another class.. using object create

Answer (score 0):

about your class HDate : the constructor HDate() can not return values ! and you can not but return out of Methode who have a type of reture...

when you make instance of your class : ( HDate hd= new HDate(); ) and it's correct. you will execute your constructor HDate(). but in your constructor you declared a local variable ((today its a local variable and it's not a global variable)) so you can not use it.

perhaps you can make that :

```
public class HDate
    {
        private string StartYear;

        public string StartYear1 {get ; set } 
        //you can write that when you use framwork 3.0 or hit

  //public HDate() { }// you can note have 2 constructor with same signature !! 


        public DateTime today;
        public HDate(){
        today = DateTime.Now;
      //Some Code here
      }

// you can make methode :
public string updateDate() // this methode will retrun a string
{
DateTime StartDate, EndDate;
// some code here
return StartDate+" ; "+EndDate ; // string is between " " ! not between ' ' ;)
}
}// end of class.. after you can declarate hd and make hd.updateDate(); good luck
```

Oh ! i forget ! you need to write : using TestInput.cs; in your file : Inputsubmit.cs :D